# Objects are not valid as react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, components

Please i know this question is duplicate but in my case i just can't find a solution. I have an object. I'm using a selector for pick this object from my state like this:

```
export const customerDetailsState = (state, selectedCustomer) => {
  if (customerState(state).getIn([CUSTOMER_SESSION, 'details'])) {
    return customerState(state).getIn([CUSTOMER_SESSION, 'details', selectedCustomer]);
  }
  return {};
};
```

I'm now make it a prop from my mapStateToProps function like this:

```
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selectedCustomer = selectedCustomerState(state);
  return {
    customerDetails: customerDetailsState(state, selectedCustomer)
  };
};
```

and then in my component: `const CustomerDetails = ({ customerDetails }) => (`

this error is showing constantly:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {lastName, firstName, identificationType, identificationCode, taxId,
>   streetName, streetNumber, city, commercialName, state, postalCode,
>   countryCode, country

My component is:

```
const CustomerDetails = ({ customerDetails }) => (
  <Card>
    <CardTitle title="Πληροφορίες Πελάτη" />
    <CardHeader
      title="Δεδομένα Altamira"
      showExpandableButton
    />
    <CardText expandable>
      <div>
        <TextField
          value={customerDetails.commercialName}
          floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_COMMERCIAL}
        /><br />
        <TextField
          value={customerDetails.lastName}
          floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_LASTNAME}
        /><br />
        <TextField
          value={customerDetails.firstName}
          floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NAME}
        /><br />
      </CardText>
   </Card>
);
```

I want to pass it as prop!! How to pass it without this error? Please dont mark it as duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: what the render function look like?

Comment: See the updated question

Comment: Are you missing a closing div `<TextField
          value={customerDetails.firstName}
          floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NAME}
        /><br />
      </div> .  <--- here
      </CardText>`

Comment: Yes my copy-paste "eat" it :P

Comment: Have you by any chance, rendered `customerDetails` directly somewhere

Comment: Nope, i used it only here

Answer (score 0):

its because your function is not returning anything. return the jsx and the problem will be solved.

```
const CustomerDetails = ({ customerDetails }) => (return(
 <Card>
   <CardTitle title="Πληροφορίες Πελάτη" />
   <CardHeader
     title="Δεδομένα Altamira"
     showExpandableButton
   />
  <CardText expandable>
  <div>
    <TextField
      value={customerDetails.commercialName}
      floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_COMMERCIAL}
    /><br />
    <TextField
      value={customerDetails.lastName}
      floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_LASTNAME}
      /><br />
      <TextField
        value={customerDetails.firstName}
        floatingLabelText={CUSTOMER_DETAILS_NAME}
       /><br />
     </CardText>
   </Card>);
);

render(){ return(this.CustomerDetails(customerDetails))};
```

Comment: same error? can you post your entire code? your render function